# Bundle .ts and .css into single files with webpack

Tags: css, typescript, webpack

I've been going around in circles with this one for a while, and I think it's time to reach out for help.

I have a weird use case where I need to transpile typescript into a single bundle, bundle .css into a single file, and also copy over any additional files that aren't .js, .ts, or .css. These files are eventually saved to a server that the software we use for our forms will use. They cannot contain .html, so most of resources I've found online don't really work in for my use case.

For whatever reason, I'm getting an error, and I don't really know where to go from here.

My devDependencies are as follows:

```
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
"ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
"typescript": "^3.7.2",
"webpack": "^4.41.2",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
```

My webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const combineLoaders = require('webpack-combine-loaders');

module.exports = {
  entry: glob.sync('./forms/**/index.ts').reduce((acc, path) => {
    const entry = path.replace('/index.ts', '')
    acc[entry] = path
    return acc
}, {}),
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true,
              experimentalWatchApi: true,
            }
          }
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
          'style-loader',
          combineLoaders([{
            loader: 'css-loader',
            query: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          }])
        )
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: './[name]/customBundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public')
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')
  ]
};
```

And here's the error I get:

```
> ci-deploy-test@1.0.0 build C:\Users\userName\Documents\git-coding\ci-deploy-test
> webpack

(node:15584) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
C:\Users\userName\Documents\git-coding\ci-deploy-test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:866
                throw new Error(
                ^

Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by instanceof Entrypoint instead
    at Chunk.get (C:\Users\userName\Documents\git-coding\ci-deploy-test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:866:9)
    at C:\Users\userName\Documents\git-coding\ci-deploy-test\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:176:48
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\userName\Documents\git-coding\ci-deploy-test\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:171:18
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\userName\Documents\git-coding\ci-deploy-test\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\userName\Documents\git-coding\ci-deploy-test\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.seal (C:\Users\userName\Documents\git-coding\ci-deploy-test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1342:27)
    at compilation.finish.err (C:\Users\userName\Documents\git-coding\ci-deploy-test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:675:18)
    at hooks.finishModules.callAsync.err (C:\Users\userName\Documents\git-coding\ci-deploy-test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1261:4)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\userName\Documents\git-coding\ci-deploy-test\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:24:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\userName\Documents\git-coding\ci-deploy-test\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.finish (C:\Users\userName\Documents\git-coding\ci-deploy-test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1253:28)
    at hooks.make.callAsync.err (C:\Users\userName\Documents\git-coding\ci-deploy-test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:672:17)
    at _done (eval at create (C:\Users\userName\Documents\git-coding\ci-deploy-test\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at _err0 (eval at create (C:\Users\userName\Documents\git-coding\ci-deploy-test\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:20:22)
    at _addModuleChain (C:\Users\userName\Documents\git-coding\ci-deploy-test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1185:12)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (C:\Users\userName\Documents\git-coding\ci-deploy-test\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1097:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ci-deploy-test@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ci-deploy-test@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-20T01_47_46_906Z-debug.log
```

UPDATE: Mostly working. Now I just need to be able to handle .scss as well.

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: './[name]/customBundle.css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css',
      ignoreOrder: false
    })
  ],
  entry: glob.sync('./forms/**/index.ts').reduce((acc, path) => {
    const entry = path.replace('/index.ts', '');
    acc[entry] = path;
    return acc;
  }, {}),
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true,
              experimentalWatchApi: true
            }
          }
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
            }
          },
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  output: {
    filename: './[name]/customBundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public')
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely related to using the ExtractTextPlugin with Webpack 4:

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin#usage

Migrate you configuration to: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll look into this and report back if it works.

Comment: (Note to self, always read github pages before installing packages and look for giant text stating it's deprecated :P )

Comment: I almost forgot to report back. This did indeed resolve the issue.